# Trouble Parsing MusicXML Files from File Paths in Python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree, musicxml

I'm working on a Python project where I need to parse MusicXML files. So far, I've been manually copying the content from these files into a string variable, and the code works perfectly. However, I'd like to make my script more user-friendly by allowing it to accept file paths instead.

Here's how I'm attempting to parse the file from a given file path:

```py
xml_file_path = r"C:\Users\myfilepath.musicxml"
tree = ET.parse(xml_file_path)
root = tree.getroot()
xml_content = ET.tostring(root, encoding="utf-8").decode("utf-8")
```

The problem I'm encountering is that when I run my code with the file path, it doesn't seem to work as expected. I'm not getting any error messages, but the parsing results are not what I'm looking for, and they often seem incomplete.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me understand what might be going wrong here, or if there's a better way to directly parse MusicXML files from file paths in Python. Any tips, suggestions, or guidance would be incredibly helpful.

Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: "they often seem incomplete" how???

Comment: if you are using windows, then use (double backslash) \\ or a (forward slash) /...

Comment: share the file `myfilepath.musicxml` and explain what is the information you need from this file

Answer (score 0):

You don’t explain, what you like to parse or what you like to do with the content?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os 

def xml_parse(filename):
    tree = ET.parse(filename)
    root = tree.getroot()
    
    for elem in root.iter():
        print(elem.tag, elem.attrib, elem.text)



if __name__ == "__main__": 
    # insert the path where you are interessted e.g.
    # path = r"C:\Users\sselt\Documents\blog_demo" 
    path = r"."
    
    for (root,dirs,files) in os.walk(path, topdown=True): 
        for filename in files:
            if filename.endswith('.xml'):
                print(filename)
                xml_parse(filename)
```

Instead of os.walk() you can let pathlib() do the job:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from pathlib import Path

def xml_parse(filename):
    print(f"File: {filename}")
    tree = ET.parse(filename)
    root = tree.getroot()
    
    for elem in root.iter():
        if elem.tag == "score-instrument" and elem.get('id') == 'P1-I1':
            print(f"{elem.find('./instrument-name').text:>17}")
        
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    # insert the path where you are interessted e.g.
    p = Path('.')
    print(p.cwd())
    print(Path.home())
    print(Path.home().parent)
    l = list(p.glob('*.xml'))

    for filename in l:
        xml_parse(filename)
```

Output from my MusicXML file:

```
File: musicXML.xml
      Wood Blocks
File: test.xml
File: outxml.xml
File: helloWorld.xml
```

Should work on Linux and Windows.

Comment: i want to find in the musicxml file an instument with a specific attribute.
here is the code:

```python
# Parse the XML
root = ET.fromstring(xml_content)

# Find the score-instrument with id "P10-I42"
target_id = "P10-I42"
instrument_name = None

for score_instrument in root.findall(".//score-instrument"):
    if score_instrument.get("id") == target_id:
        instrument_name = score_instrument.find("instrument-name").text
        break

if instrument_name:
    print(f"The instrument name for id {target_id} is: {instrument_name}")
```

Comment: @SaarKol I have edit my example. Please accept the answer, if it is helpful, Thanks.

Comment: @SaarKol: Please don't post code in comments. Edit the question instead (make sure to provide a proper [mcve]).

Comment: @Hermann12: don't answer unclear questions. Instead, request a [mcve].